# Video not Posting to Emulator through Coding

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Hey all I am trying to do a coursera course but it may be way out of date. I am trying to post a video to my emulator. All coding seems to be right as i used solution codes given by Coursera but when i use the '//' commands they stay greyed out and thus i think is the reason why it wont post to the emulator. I have the proper video format for it but the app i need to open the video on the emulator is non existent. can someone help with this please? I've cleaned the project and updated gradle to its curret version but im at a loss. here is the code in it.

```
> `MainActivity.kt:
> 
> package com.example.video_player
> 
> import android.net.Uri
> import android.os.Bundle
> import android.view.View
> import android.widget.MediaController
> import android.widget.VideoView
> import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
> 
> class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
> override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
>         //Find the VideoView class by its id     ((Each of these are greyed out))
> val videoView = findViewById<View>(R.id.testView) as VideoView
>         //Creating MediaController               ((Each of these are greyed out))
> val mediaController = MediaController(this)
> mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
>         //specify the location of media file     ((Each of these are greyed out))
> val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/raw/video1")
>         //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView      ((Each of these are greyed out)) 
> videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
> videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
> videoView.requestFocus()
> videoView.start()
>     }
> }
```

`

> ```
> `> `activity_main.xml:
> > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> > <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> > xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> > xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> > android:layout_width="match_parent"
> > android:layout_height="match_parent"
> > tools:context="com.example.video_player.MainActivity">
> > 
> >     <VideoView
> > android:id="@+id/testView"
> > android:layout_width="wrap_content"
> > android:layout_height="308dp"
> > app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
> > app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
> > app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
> > app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
> > </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
> > ``
> ```